# applying bindings to dynamically generated html

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I am creating an app to manage some list items. The app has a menu with available List Items and the user chooses some of the list items to add. The selected List items are displayed on a table, the catch is that every ListItem has a Category and every ListItem must be displayed under the same category.

This is the method to add a new ListItem:

```
self.addListItem = function () {
                let $itemsTable = $('#itemsTable');


                if (self.wineList.listItemModelsByCat.hasOwnProperty(this.category.title())) {
                    // the category is added already, just add the list item

                    self.wineList.listItemModelsByCat[this.category.title()].listItems.push({
                        item: this,
                        columnPrices : self.getColumnPricesModel()
                    })
                } else {


                    self.wineList.listItemModelsByCat[this.category.title()] = {
                        catTitle: ko.observable(this.category.title()),
                        listItems: ko.observableArray([{
                            item: this,
                            columnPrices: self.getColumnPricesModel()
                        }])
                    };

                    self.wineList.listItems.push(this);
                    self.listItems.remove(this);



                    // must create new model for this category
                    // and manage the ui

                    // add the category

                    let categoryMarkup  = '<tr>' +
                        `<td class="text-center list-category"
                                colspan="2" id="category_${this.category.id()}"> ${this.category.title()} </td>` +
                        '</tr>';

                    $itemsTable.find('tbody')
                        .append(categoryMarkup);



                    // add category items

                    let itemMarkup = '<tr class="spacer"> </tr>';

                    itemMarkup += `<tr>
                                    <td data-bind="text: wineList.listItemModelsByCat['${this.category.title()}']
                                            .listItems()
                                            .last()
                                            .item
                                            .title">
                                    </td>
                                  <td>
                                        <ul class="inline-list" data-bind="foreach: wineList.listItemModelsByCat['${this.category.title()}']
                                            .listItems()
                                            .last()
                                            .columnPrices">
                                            <li style="float: right" class="inline-list-item" >
                                                <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: price">
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>`;

                    $itemsTable.find('tbody')
                        .append(itemMarkup);


                     ko.applyBindings(self, $itemsTable.find('tbody > tr:last-child')[0])
                //
                }
            };


self.getColumnPricesModel = function() {
                let columnModel = ko.observableArray([]);

                self.wineList.columns().forEach((column) => {
                    let model = { title : ko.observable(column.title()),
                        price : ko.observable('')};

                        columnModel.push(model)
                });

                return columnModel;
            };

            self.updateColumnPricesModel = function() {
                Object.keys(self.wineList.listItemModelsByCat).forEach((key) => {
                    let item = self.wineList.listItemModelsByCat[key];
                    for (let i =0; i < item.listItems().length; i++) {
                        let listItem = item.listItems()[i];
                        listItem.columnPrices = self.getColumnPricesModel()
                    }
                })
            };
```

The problem is that the data binding doesn't work on the newly added items. Am I missing something?

Comment: I will prepare a jsFiddle to make the problem more clear.

Comment: On site snippets are preferred.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: fiddle or snippet would definitely help

Comment: @JasonSpake this is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k8dz1um7/

Comment: If you have list of your items and you are using knockout, you don't need to define html elements in strings. You can write your structure in your knockout `foreach` binding in html file and if data will be added it will show elements with working bindings. Sorry if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Gawel1908 Yes the problem is that I need to display every ListItem under it's own category. In other words if I add a ListItem with category "category1" and there is no other item with that category already added, I need a heading to the table with the category name and below the category. I hope it makes sense

Comment: @giannisf Maybe try to use the `if` binding for categories or group your array of items by cattegory. You can use `groupBy` method from lodash or underscore library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was quite simple, in my `updateColumnPricesModel`:

```
self.updateColumnPricesModel = function() {
                Object.keys(self.wineList.listItemModelsByCat).forEach((key) => {
                    let item = self.wineList.listItemModelsByCat[key];
                    for (let i =0; i < item.listItems().length; i++) {
                        let listItem = item.listItems()[i];
                        listItem.columnPrices = self.getColumnPricesModel()
                    }
                })
            };

self.getColumnPricesModel = function(isNew = true) {
    let columnModel = isNew ? ko.observableArray([]) : [];

    self.theList.selectedColumns().forEach((column) => {
      let model = {
        title: ko.observable(column.title()),
        price: ko.observable('')
      };

      columnModel.push(model)
    });

    return columnModel;
  };
```

In every update, I was setting the columnPrices to be a new `observableArray`.

`listItem.columnPrices = self.getColumnPricesModel()` I changed this to

`listItem.columnPrices(self.getColumnPricesModel(false))`

and it worked.